# how to load script first in jsp when you call from backbone

Tags: javascript, java, backbone.js

My JSP is calling from a backbone application. In this JSP, I have CSS and script tags. But some how My script is not loading first in Backbone app. Same JSP is working in Java application, but not backbone application. I tried several things like keeping script in starting of the page and end of the page. But no luck.

Is there anyway I can execute JSP script first in backbone?

I would like to execute window.location.replace(url) first from below code when ever this jsp is loaded from backbone app. But currently it is loading CSS first and redirecting another page, this is causing page delay before redirecting

```
 <script>
var entitle = "${Data.entitle}";
var optIn = "${OptIn}";
var isModel = ("${Data.Model}" == "true") ? false : true;

if(entitle == "true" && optIn == "IN") {
    showWindow("some url", true);
}


function showWindow(url, isModel) {
    if(isModel) {
        var newWindow = window.open(url,'name','height=800, width=1200, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes');

        //popup is blocked
        if(!newWindow){

             //Some Logic

            });
        }
        else if (window.focus) {
            newWindow.focus();
        }
    }
    else {
        window.location.replace(url);
    }

    return false;
}


}
</script>

<style type="text/css">

// My styles

</style>

<div class="ticket">
    // My HTML content
</div>
```

Comment: Please include some code here. No one can/will help you if they don't see any effort put into the question?

Comment: @AP. Sure. I added sample code